# jBPM6 java api: retrieve future tasks

Tags: jbpm

We have embedded in our application jbpm 6 engine as workflow engine and now we want to implement a new feature that show the list of future task to do given an actual user task.
In jbpm 6 java api there is a way to retrieve the future tasks of a given task instance?

Comment: I don't think you will have any such service provided in jBPM directly but In my view you can write your own custom code to retrieve future task from `Node`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Have you any snippets about how I can retrieve the Node from a Task Instance?